# How to login on a website that uses Spring Security from another website?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-security

For simplicity let's call the 2 sites:

- A - the site the user is already on
- B - the site that uses Spring Security where the user must get

The flow i'm trying to achieve here is the following:

- the user is logged in on site A (which knows his credentials for site B)
- the user clicks on a link on site A which takes him to site B; this also logs him in on B, so he doesn't have to enter any account information
- when the user logs out of site B he's redirected to site A

What are the possible ways/the best way to do this?

Edit:
A is a CGI app running on Apache web server. 
B runs on Tomcat. 
A SSO solution would probably fix the issue, however it's complicated to set up. I was trying to find something simpler, given that i already have access to the credentials. My first idea was to use an AJAX POST request directly on the j_spring_security_check page. However, that doesn't seem to work for some reason. (i'm new to Spring, so i was wondering if someone knows an alternative way to do this authentication).

Comment: Are A and B on the same domain?

Comment: Are both sites under your control?

Comment: Yes, both sites are on the same domain, and under my control.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's called Single Sign On (SSO) and there is a whole slew of different solutions, platforms and products to enable it. It depends a lot on what application server and frameworks you are using and platforms you are running on so if you do a little searching for SSO solutions for your app-server and frameworks (ie spring security), you're sure to come across a solution.

Comment: A is a CGI app running on Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

here is my proposal, provided both A and B are under your control

there is a link in A -> www.a.com/login-to-b

when a user clicks the link, it redirects the user to (this url is generated at A server side)

www.b.com/single-sign-on?user_id=123&timestamp=1234567&token=hash(user_id+timestamp+your-secret-key)

hash can be md5 or sha1, your choice

if A and B both possess the same secret key

then B can verify the information sent from A by applying the hash again

```
boolean isValid = hash(request.getParameter("user_id") + 
                       request.getParameter("timestamp") + 
                       KEY).equals(request.getParameter("hash");
```

the timestamp is there is prevent replay attack

so after B verify the hash, B also needs to check whether the timestamp is expired or not

```
// suppose we make it 5 sec to expire
boolean isExpired = System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp < 5000;
```

if both checks pass, then B can be sure that the redirect request really comes from www.a.com with a legitimate user

now you know the user_id at B, then do your application specific stuff to make the user recognized by B